# The "Ross-A-Tron" joke

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In the 11th episode of the 7th series of *Friends* - *The One With All The Cheesecakes* Ross tries to use his "new nickname":

> Ross: Hey Joe, while you’re over there how about another beer for the
>   Ross-A-Tron?
>
> Joey: The Ross—Is that back?!! (Chandler motions no.)

Could someone explain Joey's and Chandler's reaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a silly nickname that Ross liked and the rest of the gang hated. From [earlier in the scene](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_All_The_Cheesecakes/Transcript):

> **Phoebe:** Well, I'll tell you Rachel Karen Green, I had plans with Joey tonight and he left me this note. (Hands it to Rachel.)
>
> **Rachel:** (reading the note) "Pheebs, can't make it, got a date. Talk to you later. Big Daddy." (Laughs) Big Daddy?
>
> **Phoebe:** Oh that's a nickname we were trying out.
>
> **Ross:** Hey, y'know what nickname never caught on? ***The Ross-A-Tron!*** (Monica shakes her head in disgust.)

Seems Ross tried out this nickname before and it didn't go so well. Joey is upset that they might have to call Ross by that stupid name again, but Chandler silently assures him that they won't.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Joey knew about this nickname. I though that's something that Ross made up in the earlier scene. Thanks for the explanation.